# what is the best way to loop through large data with insert query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

i have to insert large data in lets say 20k i doubt i have written an optimised query.

what it does:

1. fetches user's records with sql fulfilling some criteria it fetches more than 1k-20k users in an active record array in merge_user_records
2. slices in batch of 100 users from array of activerecord of 1k-20k users
3. loops through merge_user records and finds user from User model user user_id in merge_user_records
4. still in loop user calls a method construct_user_notifications to insert user_notifications for each user.
5. still in loop finds devices of user.
6. run a loop in device to send push notification on every device.
7. loop ends

here is the code.

```
merge_users = MergeField.get_user_field_values(notification_template.merge_field, scope_users) #=> **returns users 1k - 20k**
if merge_users.present?
  merge_users.each_slice(100) do |record|
    record.each do |user_record|
      user = User.find_by(id: user_record.user_id)
      text = notification_template.title
      notification_template.description = MustacheDescription.render(notification_template, user_record)
      text += " " + notification_template.description
      Rails.logger.info "Merge field message: #{notification_template.description}"
      construct_user_notifications(notification_template, user_record.user_id) #=> **this calls another method below which actually create notifications for every user.**
      badge = (notification_template.display_screen == "suggestion") ? user.unread_suggestion_notifications.count : user.unread_option_notifications.count
      devices = user.devices.with_notification_token
      if devices.present?
        devices.each do |device|
          PushNotification.notify_ios(text, device.notification_token, badge, {screen: notification_template.display_screen})
          Rails.logger.info "Sending push to user_id #{user_record.user_id} token #{device.notification_token}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

def self.construct_user_notifications(notification_template, user_id)
  notification_template.user_notifications.build.tap do |user_notification|
    user_notification.title = notification_template.title
    user_notification.subtitle = notification_template.subtitle
    user_notification.description = notification_template.description
    user_notification.merge_field = notification_template.merge_field
    user_notification.cta = notification_template.cta
    user_notification.cta_key = notification_template.cta_key
    user_notification.secondary_cta = notification_template.secondary_cta
    user_notification.secondary_cta_key = notification_template.secondary_cta_key
    user_notification.show_useful = notification_template.show_useful
    user_notification.category = notification_template.category
    user_notification.display_screen = notification_template.display_screen
    user_notification.sent_at = Time.current
    user_notification.user_id = user_id
    user_notification.filter_preferences = notification_template.filter_preferences
    user_notification.save
  end
end
```

I have tested this for 100 users and it takes 30-40 secs. god knows how much it would take for 20k users in prod.

Comment: `PushNotification` could be eating a lot of time here. Can you defer that?

Comment: take a look at [activerecord-import](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/zdennis/activerecord-import/ActiveRecord%2FBase.import), it handles large amount of insert pretty well

Comment: Why are you fetching all those users, and then finding each User individually? And what is your performance target for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. `find_by` in the loop

`user = User.find_by(id: user.user_id)` would query 20k times! We can avoid this by putting this out of `each` loop:

```
merge_users.each_slice(100) do |users|
  users = User.where(id: users.map(&:user_id))
  users.each do |user|
    # loop
  end
end
```

---

#### 2. logger level

Change `info` to `debug`. Disk IO is always slow.

---

#### 3. `construct_user_notifications` function

`notification_template.user_notifications.build` would allocate 20k objects. GC would be a problem, too.

Please only build the attributes, and save it later.

For example:

```
def self.construct_user_notifications(notification_template, user_id)
  {
      title: notification_template.title,
      subtitle: notification_template.subtitle,
      description: notification_template.description,
      merge_field: notification_template.merge_field,
      cta: notification_template.cta,
      cta_key: notification_template.cta_key,
      secondary_cta: notification_template.secondary_cta,
      secondary_cta_key: notification_template.secondary_cta_key,
      show_useful: notification_template.show_useful,
      category: notification_template.category,
      display_screen: notification_template.display_screen,
      sent_at: Time.current,
      user_id: user_id,
      filter_preferences: notification_template.filter_preferences, 
      # more attributes
  }
end
```

---

#### 4. `badge` queries

`badge = (notification_template.display_screen == "suggestion") ? user.unread_suggestion_notifications.count : user.unread_option_notifications.count`

This is unnecessary unless `devices` are present.

You can query badges later.

---

#### 5. push notification

`PushNotification.notify_ios(text, device.notification_token, badge, {screen: notification_template.display_screen})`

This may have some http requests, which is quite slow.

You should use `sidekiq` or `resque` to do it in a background job.

#### 6. save `user_notifications`

Have a look at [`activerecord-import`](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem. Batch insert is more efficient.

### Example

```
merge_users = MergeField.get_user_field_values(notification_template.merge_field, scope_users) #=> **returns users 1k - 20k**

merge_users.each_slice(500) do |users|
  users = User.where(id: users.map(&:user_id))
  user_notifications = Set.new

  users.each do |user|
    text = notification_template.title
    notification_template.description = MustacheDescription.render(notification_template, user)
    text += " " + notification_template.description
    Rails.logger.debug "Merge field message: #{notification_template.description}"

    user_notifications.add construct_user_notifications(notification_template, user.user_id)

    # do this asynchronously
    push_notification(notification_template, user_id)
  end

  UserNotification.import(user_notifications.first.keys, user_notifications.to_a)
end

def self.push_notification(notification_template, user_id)
  devices = Device.where(user_id: user_id).with_notification_token.pluck(:notification_token)
  if devices.present?
    badge = (notification_template.display_screen == "suggestion") ? UnreadSuggestionNotification.where(user_id: user_id).count : UnreadOptionNotification.where(user_id: user_id).count
    devices.each do |device|
      PushNotification.notify_ios(text, device.notification_token, badge, {screen: notification_template.display_screen})
      Rails.logger.debug "Sending push to user_id #{user_id} token #{device.notification_token}"
    end
  end
end


def self.construct_user_notifications(notification_template, user_id)
  {
      title: notification_template.title,
      subtitle: notification_template.subtitle,
      description: notification_template.description,
      merge_field: notification_template.merge_field,
      cta: notification_template.cta,
      cta_key: notification_template.cta_key,
      secondary_cta: notification_template.secondary_cta,
      secondary_cta_key: notification_template.secondary_cta_key,
      show_useful: notification_template.show_useful,
      category: notification_template.category,
      display_screen: notification_template.display_screen,
      sent_at: Time.current,
      user_id: user_id,
      filter_preferences: notification_template.filter_preferences,
      # more attributes
  }
end
```

Comment: hey @scorix thanks so much for the detailed breakdown of tasks. i have implemented it and it seems pretty faster for 1k users. thanks kudos to you.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest wrapping the inner contents of loop in a transaction block which will run all the queries in one go at the end, rather than piecemeal. That will group all the queries for each user into a single transaction to be ran at the same time:

```
merge_users.each_slice(100) do |record|
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  // code
  end

  if devices.present?
    devices.each do |device|
      PushNotification.notify_ios(text,device.notification_token,badge,{screen: notification_template.display_screen})
      Rails.logger.info  "Sending push to user_id #{user_record.user_id} token #{device.notification_token}"
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more information on transactions here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Finally I would suggest instead of doing the PushNotification.notifify_ios directly in the block you should use DelayedJob or similar to run the jobs in the background. This would mean all the method calls would be processed later in the background after the code itself has ran, rather than within the loop itself.

That would look like:

```
if devices.present?
    devices.each do |device|
      PushNotification.delay.notify_ios(text,device.notification_token,badge,{screen: notification_template.display_screen})
      Rails.logger.info  "Sending push to user_id #{user_record.user_id} token #{device.notification_token}"
    end
  end
```

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job